# How to redirect Spring security concurrent session control 'message' on login screen?

Tags: spring, spring-security, concurrency

I have web application, in which I have used Spring framework.
For the concurrent session control I have use spring feature where only 1 logged in session will be maintained for 1 user as soon as that user logs in to another session , he/her previous session will be expired.

Now in this case I am getting this message "*This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent logins being attempted as the same user).*"

But I get this message on complete white page on browser. I want this message to come on my login screen only.

Here is the part of my spring security xml where I have handled concurrent session for user.

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpired" session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?error=alreadyLogin">
                    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
</security:session-management>
```

Any links specially for customizing this message and redirecting this message on desired web application page will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Original XML entry in spring-security.xml

```
<security:session-management session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?error=alreadyLogin">
                    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
</security:session-management>
```

Just You have to added following parameter in xml to redirect the Login expired action or invalid session url

expired-url="url value"

invalid-session-url="url value"

Modified XML entry

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpired" session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?error=alreadyLogin">
                    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.jsp?error=sessionExpiredDuplicateLogin" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
</security:session-management>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this working in a spring boot app with REST APIs, check the below code sample. By default, when a session expires due to concurrent logins, the response code would be 200. The below code sample changes that to 401.

```
.sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> {
    httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.maximumSessions(1);
    httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionConcurrency(concurrencyControlConfigurer -> {
        concurrencyControlConfigurer.maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false);
        concurrencyControlConfigurer.expiredSessionStrategy(event -> {
            HttpServletResponse response = event.getResponse();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.getWriter().print("{\"responseCode\":\"FAILURE\" , \"error\":\"This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent logins being " +
                    "attempted as the same user).\"}");
            response.flushBuffer();
        });
    });
})
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/session-management.html#ns-concurrent-sessions

Answer (score 0):

In the jar spring-security-core there are .properties files.

You will need to override the properties you want with your custom messages in your application.

Comment: 'How to do' would be most appropriate instead of 'what to do'. Answers mostly go in 'How to do'.